# Is this transformation really measure preserving?

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I've encountered the following example in "Ergodic Theory, with a view towards Number Theory", by Einsiedler and Ward.
The writers introduce the system $(\mathbb{R}, \mu ,T)$ where $\mu$ and $T$ are defined as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
  \mu([a,b]) &= \intop_a^b \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} \\
  T(x) &= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{1}{x}) &: x\neq0 \\
                        0\ &: x=0
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
The relevant sigma-algebra is not explicitly named, so I guess it is Borel's.

This system is claimed to be measure preserving, and the argument for that claim is that for every $f\in L^1$, the substitution $y=Tx$ proves the equality:

$$
\intop_{-\infty}^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} =\intop_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) \frac{dy}{\pi(1+y^2)} 
$$

I can see why the claim follows from the equality, but I can't convince myself this equality is true - I'm pretty sure we have inequality for $f=id$, which is $L^1$ with respect to the measure we deal with.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: I don't think $f=\text{id}$ is in $L_1$ for the given measure, since the measure is a Cauchy distribution, whose first moment is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality is correct.

\begin{align}
\intop_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) \frac{dy}{\pi(1+y^2)} &= \intop_0^\infty f(T(x)) \frac{d(T(x))}{\pi(1+(T(x))^2)} = \\ 
&= \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{d(\frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{1}{x}))}{\pi(1+(\frac{1}{2}(x-\frac{1}{x}))^2)} = \\ 
&= \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{x^2})dx}{\frac{1}{4}\pi(4+(x-\frac{1}{x})^2)} = \\ 
&= \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{2(1+\frac{1}{x^2})dx}{\pi(4+x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}-2)} = \\ 
&= \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{2(1+\frac{1}{x^2})dx}{\pi(2+x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})} = \\ 
&= \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{2(1+\frac{1}{x^2})dx}{\pi(1+\frac{1}{x^2})(1+x^2)} = \\ 
&= 2\intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \\ 
&= \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} + \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \\  
&= \intop_0^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} + \intop_{-\infty}^0 f \circ T(x) \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \\ 
&= \intop_{-\infty}^\infty f \circ T(x) \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} 
\end{align}

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226884590_The_ergodic_infinite_measure_preserving_transformation_of_boole

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Its is a nice 17 pages paper. However, the transformation $\phi$ in the paper is different from $T$ here and the measure in the paper is just the Lebesgue measure. The OP question here is much simpler.